# How can i fetch data from mysql using axios?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios

I want to fetch / get data from my mysql database in my laravel project. Here i can save data and i wrote a script to show data list using axios and javascript but showing error.
Can you help to where is my error?

here is my Routes

```
Route::get('/blogs', [BlgoCategoryController::class, 'index'])->name('categories.index');
Route::get('/blogs/{category}', [BlgoCategoryController::class, 'show'])->name('categories.show');
Route::post('/blogs', [BlgoCategoryController::class, 'store'])->name('categories.store');
Route::put('/blogs/{category}', [BlgoCategoryController::class, 'update'])->name('categories.update');
Route::delete('/blogs/{category}', [BlgoCategoryController::class, 'destroy'])->name('categories.destroy');
```

I wrote these scripts in my controller file

```
class BlgoCategoryController extends Controller {



public function index(Request $request) {
    $perPage = $request->perPage ?? 5;
    $keyword = $request->keyword;

    $query = BlogCategory::query();

    if ($keyword) {
        $query = $query->where('category_name', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%');
    }

    $categories = $query->orderByDesc('id')->paginate($perPage)->withQueryString();

    return view('admin.blogs.categories', compact('categories'));
}

public function show(BlogCategory $category) {
    return $category;
}
//Store News Customer
function store(Request $request){
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'category_name' => 'required|string|max:50'
    ]);

    $category = BlogCategory::create($validated);
    return response()->json($category, Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}

public function update(Request $request, BlogCategory $category) {
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'category_name' => 'required|string|max:50'
    ]);

    $category->update($validated);

    return response()->json($category);
}

public function destroy(BlogCategory $category) {
    $category->delete();

    return response()->json(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
} }
```

I want to fetch data in this view file

```
<div id="loader" class="LoadingOverlay d-none">
    <div class="Line-Progress">
        <div class="indeterminate"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card shadow">
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <h5>{{__('Blog Categories')}}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#categoryModal">
                    {{__('Add Category')}}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 px-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Per Page</label>
                    <select id="perPage" class="form-control form-select-sm form-select">
                        <option>5</option>
                        <option>10</option>
                        <option>15</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 px-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Search</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input value="" type="text" id="keyword" class="form-control">
                        <button class="form-control btn btn-success" type="button" id="searchButton">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12 p-2 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="table-responsive bg-white rounded-3 p-2">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableData">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="bg-light">
                                <th>{{__('Category ID')}}</th>
                                <th>{{__('Category Name')}}</th>
                                <th>{{__('Category Slug')}}</th>
                                <th>{{__('Action')}}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tableList">
                        
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-2 p-2">
                <div class="">
                    <button onclick="handlePrevious()" id="previousButton" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">{{__('Previous')}}</button>
                    <button onclick="handleNext()" id="nextButton" class="btn btn-sm mx-1 btn-success">{{__('Next')}}</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my Javascript

```
let currentPage = 1

// Function to fetch and display the list of customers
async function getList() {
    const perPage = document.getElementById("perPage").value
    const keyword = document.getElementById("keyword").value

    try {
        function showLoader() {
            document.getElementById('loader').classList.remove('d-none')
        }
        const response = await axios.get(
            `/blogs?page=${currentPage}&perPage=${perPage}&keyword=${keyword}`)
            console.log(response);
        updateTable(response.data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching customer data:', error);
    } finally {
        function hideLoader() {
            document.getElementById('loader').classList.add('d-none')
        }
    }
}

// Function to update the table with customer data
function updateTable(data) {
const tableList = document.getElementById("tableList");

    // Check if there are no categories to display
    if (!data.data.length) {
        tableList.innerHTML = '<tr><td colspan="4" class="text-center">No categories found.</td></tr>';
        return;
    }

    // Build the rows HTML string
    const rowsHtml = data.data.map(category => {
        return `<tr>
                    <td>${category.id}</td>
                    <td>${category.category_name}</td>
                    <td>${category.category_slug}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button data-id="${category.id}" class="btn editBtn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Edit</button>
                        <button data-id="${category.id}" class="btn deleteBtn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>`;
    }).join('');

    // Update the table with the new rows
    tableList.innerHTML = rowsHtml;
}


// Event listeners for pagination and search
document.getElementById('perPage').addEventListener('change', () => {
    currentPage = 1
    getList()
})


document.getElementById('searchButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
    currentPage = 1
    getList()
})

// Functions for handling pagination buttons
function handlePrevious() {
    if (currentPage > 1) {
        currentPage--
        getList()
    }
}

function handleNext() {
    currentPage++
    getList()
}

// Function to delete a customer
async function deleteCategory(id) {
    let isConfirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this category?")
    if (isConfirmed) {
        try {
            function showLoader() {
            document.getElementById('loader').classList.remove('d-none')
        }
            await axios.delete(`/blogs/${id}`)
            getList()
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error deleting category:', error)
        } finally {
            function hideLoader() {
            document.getElementById('loader').classList.add('d-none')
        }
        }
    }
}

// Attach event listeners to dynamically created buttons
document.getElementById('tableList').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const target = event.target

    if (target.classList.contains('deleteBtn')) {
        const categoryId = target.getAttribute('data-id')
        deleteCategory(categoryId)
    }

    if (target.classList.contains('editBtn')) {
        const categoryId = target.getAttribute('data-id')
        fillUpUpdateForm(categoryId)
    }
})

// Initial list fetch
getList()
```

Please help me to show the data list.

Comment: It's hard to tell the error, if you do not use any testing frameworks you can start with your browser console to debug if it does there are any errors with your front end, check the network tab to check the response from server-side. this will give you a clue about what's going on.

Comment: it is showing   blogs:672 Error fetching customer data: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Comment: Make sure the returned data is an array. What is the format of the response data?

Comment: const response = await axios.get(
                `/blogs?page=${currentPage}&perPage=${perPage}&keyword=${keyword}`)
                console.log(response);
            updateTable(response.data)

Comment: Can you  replace console.log(response) by
console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2))
and show us what it prints in the browser console?

Comment: Error fetching customer data: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at updateTable (blogs:685:24)
    at getList (blogs:670:13)

Comment: You have a `console.log(response)` before your `updateTable(response.data)` call. What does that actually output? Also, you're passing in `response.data` to `updateTable(response.data)` and then in that function, you're using `data.data.length`, which means you expect the data to be `response.data.data`. It also seems like axios is calling the route `/blogs`, which seem to just return a view, but your code treats the response like an object? There are a lot of irrelevant code in the question and not enough debugging info/clear expectations to fully get what you expect to happen, and why.

Comment: Hi MicroWeb Technology and welcome to stackoverflow. It will help others a lot to understand your problem if you include relevant error messages in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your index function of BlgoCategory returns a view, should that not be a “ response()->json”?

If you want to display the view and then update with axios you need 2 endpoints. One returning the view and the other the json for the axios call